# How to switch LocationRequest priority dynamically?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-fusedlocation

I'm newbie with Google's Fused Location API and I need my app to switch from `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` to `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`, for example, when the device is stationary to conserve battery, and vice versa. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.